# Typescript dectect error on vueuse source code

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vueuse

I completed my project on vue and want to build for production. When I enter `yarn build`, Typescript detects errors in the `@vueuse/core` source

```
ERROR in /path/to/project/node_modules/@vueuse/shared/index.d.ts(112,5):
112:5 Property or signature expected.
    110 |  */
    111 | declare type RemovableRef<T> = Omit<Ref<T>, 'value'> & {
  > 112 |     get value(): T;
        |     ^
    113 |     set value(value: T | null | undefined);
    114 | };
    115 | /**
```

package.json

```json
{
...
  "dependencies": {
...
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^9.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-composition-api": "^0.0.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.8",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to `"typescript": "^4.4.4"`

https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/issues/876